# c# serial port data loss

Tags: c#, serial-port, data-loss

I have written a C# program to receive data on COM2 port. The baud rate is set as 115200. The sender is sending the data at 115200bps. My program is losing a few bytes ocassionally. I am calling `ReadByte` method to read the data in a `while(true)` loop from the com port.

I have few questions:

- When the baud rate is set high, should I expect to lose data? if yes, why?
- I am setting the readbuffer size as 100*1024*1024. Does this set the serial driver buffer size to 100*1024*1024?

Any thoughts on how to debug this problem?

Comment: What do you do besides `ReadByte` inside the while loop?  How long does the processing take?

Comment: After reading the byte from the Serial port, it would be put it in to a buffer until the buffer reaches 12 bytes. once it reaches 12 bytes, it would be compared against the defined commands which would take very less time.

Comment: You should ensure you're using flow control if you're not already doing so.

Comment: The answers for this question may also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222455/how-do-i-force-a-serial-port-write-method-to-wait-for-the-line-to-clear-before-se

Answer (score 5):

A receive buffer size of 100*1024*1024 is HUGE! I would seriously doubt you need this size at all, and certainly not for the actual serial port buffer.

It could be that you are overflowing the physical receive buffer of the receiver, so you may have to look into using flow control. This will effectively enable your Receiver to say to your Transmitter *"Hang on, stop sending for a while, let me deal with what I have first."*

Hardware flow-control is (commonly) utilised through the RTS (Request To Send) and CTS (Clear To Send) pins.

Take a look at [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO-11.html) article, which explains a bit more about it.

I would personally recommend leaving the ReceivedBytesThreshold property of the serial port to its default value of 1, and then handling the DataReceived event. Who knows, maybe tomorrow you will need to read a message of 20 bytes, or perhaps 5 bytes. Maybe you will need to read messages of variable length in the future? Leaving the threshold at 1 will mean that you can handle any and all bytes that will be received, now and in the future.

This threshold will mean the event will fire when there is ***at least*** 1 byte in the buffer. There maybe more, and probably will be. Note that it does **NOT** necessarily mean it will fire for every single byte received. On each event, you need to check the BytesToRead property and read this many into your own buffer.

It is worth repeating that the event will **NOT** necessarily fire for every single byte received.

Also, it is best to do as little as possible within the DataReceived event handler. Read in any bytes received into your buffer, and perhaps add completed messages into a queue for further processing, but do little else.

Also note that the ***standard*** maximum spec of [RS232](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/RS-232_specs.html) is a speed of 19200 baud and a length of cable of 50 feet. Anything above that is undefined. Higher speeds generally need better cable (lower capacitance) and shorter cable lengths. Make sure it is screened and not running near other 'noisy' items such as motors, motor inverters, live cables etc.

Comment: I have added data received event and set receive byte thresold to 1. I observed that the other threads got affected with this received event. Can that happen? There are 4 timers.timer defined which raises timer events. As soon as Serial port is received, the timer events are not firing at their defined intervals.it is offset by 1 or 2 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

> When the baud rate is set high, should I expect to lose data? if yes, why?

Not necessarily. It could happen due to a bad physical connection (too long).

> I am setting the readbuffer size as 100*1024*1024

That should be (way) more than enough.

Having said that, looping and reading single bytes is not the most efficient way to read a Port.

You could hook up to the DataReceived event and set ReceivedBytesThreshold=12. That way you can always just Read(Buffer, 0, 12)