# Serial port read rate in C#

Tags: c#, mfc, serial-port

I'm developing an application under C# to read some data from a hardware which is connected to a serial port.

Basically, the hardware sends its position (X, Y, Z) and its temperature along with a couple of other decimal values via serial port.

I'd like to be able to have a scan rate as fast as 10 milliseconds; Meaning I'd like to read the temperature, position and other values every 10 milliseconds from the port.

There is an MFC application available with the hardware which is able to read data at this rate. Is it possible to have the same performance in C#? I don't have the hardware available now so I don't know if this is possible using C#.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# serial port data loss](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568754/c-serial-port-data-loss)

Comment: @Hightechrider: I don't consider this as a duplicate. But thanks, that post had some good info.

Comment: Ten msec is not a rate that ever makes sense.  It is way too fast for a human to ever observe.  It is way too fast for Windows to ever reliably and consistently keep up with.  Occasionally losing the CPU for hundreds of msec worst-case is normal.  The .NET garbage collector can make this a lot worse.  This isn't otherwise going to get a C# program ever in trouble.  It is going to get your system in trouble if you think that 10 msec is important.

Comment: @Hans: You have to consider that I want to record the data in a database (or file) and then query some statistics. So it's not just what your eyes can see. And it makes sense in some situation. (like this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to send around 20 bytes (as estimations of 6 fields, 3 chars each) every 10 ms then you need at least 16k baud which is not much. Actually I have great doubts that C# is sooo slow to fail handling serial port communication.

If you know serial communication parameters of your hardware then it should be easy to use it from C#. I only know how to use it from Win32 API, you need CreateFile, , SetCommTimeouts, SetCommState and ReadFile calls. It seems that this functions are accessible from C# too.

If you don't know the parameters of this serial port, it may be possible to get them with a serial port sniffer however I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. is there going to be any cons using c# instead of mfc? (e.g. garbage collectors make is slower or I lose some functionality?

Comment: @Kamyar: as I see you don't need real time processing of your data so you just have to check whether your data is delivered reliably to your host and bufferization in the driver works right. If some kind of timestamp or id is sent in the packets then you can if data gets lost. If you only need to push data to a database then you can write a C++ console application that fills the database and a GUI (MFC or C#, what you prefer) app that processes the data.

Comment: Well, the customer want to see the data real-time and store it. So the program should be able to do both. However based on your answer, I guess there shouldn't be any problem. right?

Comment: @Kamyar: I if had MFC source code I wouldn't rewrite it in C#. If I had to write from scratch I'd prefer C# because I don't like MFC. Anyway all the problems if any will become apparent in the first prototype

Comment: Actually, I have to do from scratch. That's why I want to use C#. Thanks so much for the answers.